# Load sharing across multiple interfaces using tc

Tags: network-interface, tc, traffic

I created a simple topology in GENI (http://www.geni.net/) and it looks like the following:

A --- Router_1 === Router_2 --- B (Note that there are two links between routers 1 and 2.)

I am trying to load share the traffic across both the links, i.e., between the routers, when the traffic flows from A to B. To do this, I used the following commands at router 1.

```
sudo modprobe sch_teql
sudo tc qdisc add dev eth1 root teql0
sudo tc qdisc add dev eth3 root teql0
sudo ip link set dev teql0 up
```

But the load sharing is not happening and packets are always going via eth1. Any idea what I am missing?